# Angular 5 JSPDF missing image

Tags: angular, jspdf

I am using angular 5 and JSPDF to download HTML as PDF. The problem I am facing
is that the PDF is downloaded without image loaded in it.
[Reference Link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/convert-html-to-pdf-using-angular-6/)
[image: Desired Output]

[image: Output without image]

Answer (score 0):

use html2canvas with version html2canvas@0.5.0-beta4 
for ts file you can refer this code:

```js
 getImage() {
    let imgData;
    html2canvas(document.getElementById('element-to-print'), {
         onrendered: function (canvas) {
          imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
          imgData = imgData.split(',')[1];
          console.log('Image Code', JSON.stringify(imgData));
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```js
    var data = document.getElementById('element-to-print');
    html2canvas(data,
      {
        height: window.outerHeight + window.innerHeight,
        width: window.outerWidth + window.innerWidth,
        windowHeight: window.outerHeight + window.innerHeight,
        windowWidth: window.outerWidth + window.innerWidth,
        scrollX: 0,
        scrollY: 0
      }
    ).then(canvas => {
      var pdf = new jsPDF("l", "mm", "a4");
      var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      var width = pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
      var height = pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight();
      pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 0, width, height);
      pdf.save('jspdfcompleteimage.pdf');
    });
```

It show the complete html, Good Luck!